# USB Ethernet Adapter Link Local - DHCP Assignment for Link-Local Not Working

Tags: windows-7, dhcp

I have a rather interesting problem with a Belcarra USBLAN ethernet adapter. According to the manufacturer's tools my host adapter is getting an IP address. According to Windows, however, it is not.

**ipconfig /release "Local Area Connection 3" Output:**

```
An error occurred while releasing interface Local Area Connection 3 : The parameter is incorrect.
```

**ipconfig output:**

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4f5:91be:8885:c959%77
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**Belcarra Info:**

```
IOCTL_USBLAN_DEVICE_INFO:[0] idVendor: NNNN idProduct:   64 devIP:  28efea9 hostIp:  18efea9
```

FYI: An address like 169.254.142.1 shows up as 018efea9 above.

Belcarra's device driver is configured to provide DHCP for both the host adapter as well as my hardware device. Our configuration makes use of link-local DHCP, so traffic is only routed between the device and the PC.

This makes it nearly impossible to search for good reference because *most* people who run into a 169.254.x.x address are dealing with non-functional DHCP. In my case, an address like 169.254.142.2 is correct!

On my Windows 7 machine, I am seeing the driver assign a DHCP address to both the host and the device, but Windows appears to ignore it. The adapter shows up as an unidentified network. I'm working with the manufacturer on the issue, but thought I'd post a question here and see if anyone has ideas for Windows.

Belcarra can't reproduce my issue and they've asked me to test on a clean instance of Windows - which makes sense but still doesn't fix my issue. I also can't get the adapter to show up in Wireshark, which leads me to believe something is wrong with my network adapter configuration.

Are there any ways of getting Windows to avoid the autoconf process? Or perhaps some networking magic I can try? I have net filter drivers for Wireshark and VirtualBox installed. The config works on an older 2.3.x driver, but not on the newer 2.4.x driver.

Suggested tags I couldn't use because of noob rep:
belcarra, usblan, link-local, dhcp, windows-7

Comment: Link to Microsoft cross-posted question: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-dhcp-ignored-link-local-usblan/d45a5f8c-e5c9-4589-a4ee-f50738034345

Comment: Link to Technet cross-posted question: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/b130594b-9fd3-4118-a322-88228728ac45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a configuration issue with the vendor's driver settings. A clean install did not have any errors. Upgrading from the 2.3.x driver to the 2.4.x driver left an entry that caused the problem.

**Remove this registry key:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ManufacturerName\UseClientIP
```